# List is suddenly changed, eventhough i dont change it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, deep-copy

I have quite complicated code. There are three lists. Told in short - list1 and comparsion list should be compared, and if there is found some specific match, we add values from list1 to list2. The whole code is following

```
list1 = [['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0'], ['item3', ['item4'], '107', '2'], ['item4.5', ['item5', 'item4.5 aaa'], '120', '2'], ['item6', ['item6 item6 aaa'], '127', '1'], ['item7', ['item7 item7 aaa'], '129', '1']]
comparsion_list = [['item1', ['item2'], 'unknown'], ['item3', ['item4'], 'unknown'], ['item4.5', ['item5', 'item4.5 aaa'], 'unknown'], ['item6', ['item6 item6 aaa'], 'unknown']]
list2 = [['category', ['keywords'], ['long-names'], 'amount', 'amount2'],['empty', ['empty'], ['empty'], 'empty', 'empty']]

for a in range(len(comparsion_list)): #we go trough comparsion_list -start number is 1, end is category len
    for i in range(len(list1)): #and compare them with each item of list1

        if list1[i][1][0] in comparsion_list[a][1] and comparsion_list[a][2] not in [x[0] for x in list2]:
            list2.append([comparsion_list[a][2]]) #append item to list2 as list (to create row)
            list2[-1].append([list1[i][0]])
            list2[-1].append(list1[i][1])
            print("list1 before elif is: "+str(list1[0]))  #just for testing - everything still ok

        elif list1[i][1][0] in comparsion_list[a][1] and comparsion_list[a][2] == list2[-1][0]:
            print("list1 after elif is: "+str(list1[0])) #just for testing - not ok!
            list2[-1][2].extend(list1[i][1])
```

But output is following:

```
list1 before elif is: ['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0']
list1 after elif is: ['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0']
list1 after elif is: ['item1', ['item2', 'item4'], '0', '0']
list1 after elif is: ['item1', ['item2', 'item4', 'item5', 'item4.5 aaa'], '0', '0']
```

As you can see, list1 is changed, but i did not changed it all in code! there are even no references, as it is always deep copy, and deep_of_list1 remains unchanged. I thought that expected output should look like this:

```
list1 before elif is: ['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0']
list1 after elif is: ['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0']
list1 after elif is: ['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0']
list1 after elif is: ['item1', ['item2'], '0', '0']
```

But when i remove this line (from elif statement):

```
    list2[-1][2].extend(list1[i][1])
```

Then output is ok (the second one).
How's that possible? What am i missing?

Comment: Please make a [MCVE] and strip your question from code that's not necessary for the question.

Comment: Your code snippet is such a mess that I gave up trying to understand it - it's line noise, really. And stuff like `deep_of_list1 = deepcopy(list1);
list1 = deepcopy(deep_of_list1)` really doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you think your deepcopies should protect you from this? You are clearly making various appends etc of mutable objects, then mutating those...

Comment: Well, my question is, that how is possible thatn list1 changed, if there were no changes made to it (no appends/extends, it is no reference), and when i remove last line where i append to list2, it is ok...

Comment: @AndreasBekkelund what do you mean "it is no reference"? You clearly `.append` references to items inside `list1` into `list2`, then you mutate items in `list2`, which could be the same items in `list1`...  You keep repeating "there are no references", but that is obviously false, so either you misunderstand what a deepcopy does or there is some miscommunication

Answer (score 2):

You are appending references to `list1` elements to `list2`. One of these elements is a mutable (`list`) itself. Your trouble is solved if you force creation of a new memory object by explicitly copying the list.

```
list2[-1].append(list1[i][1].copy()) #in the 'if' part of the code.
```

Apart from that, I'd probably refactor the entire monster..